# RPM -resign appending signature instead of replacing one

Tags: rpm

`rpm --resign <package name>` ideally should replace the existing signature. But, the users have been complaining that the signature is being appended to the existing one, much like the `rpm --addsign` option.

How is it possible to check if the signature is being replaced or added?

I followed 2 methods.

1. Simple size verification - both addsign and resign result in the increase of the size of the source rpm package.
2. We used the command `rpm -Kv <package name>`, it lists that many number of verifications as the number of times I ran the `resign` command. Does it prove that the `resign` is also adding the signature rather than replacing it?

How to solve the issue?

Many thanks for the help

Comment: What version of rpm is this with? That used to be something that rpm could do but I believe isn't something that is done anymore. Both `--addsign` and `--resign` should, at this point (and I'm including CentOS 5-era rpm in "at this point"), only be replacing. What are people complaining about specifically? Can you show the `rpm -Kv` output from an unsigned package, from a package with `--resign` once and then from a package with `--resign` multiple times?

Comment: Hi, The rpm version is 4.4.2.3. The out put of the command `rpm -Kv` for one and multiple signing operations is pasted below:

Comment: `# rpm -Kv usbfpga_controller-3.5.6-0.i386.rpm
usbfpga_controller-3.5.6-0.i386.rpm:
    Header SHA1 digest: OK (782e7a953f50010d05013964f6ffa4ea2bab9045)
    MD5 digest: OK (41aff697b960dfd3fd4a86b84690fdd8)`

Comment: # rpm -Kv usbfpga_controller-3.5.6-0.i386.rpm
usbfpga_controller-3.5.6-0.i386.rpm:
    Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 66dd4aad
    Header SHA1 digest: OK (782e7a953f50010d05013964f6ffa4ea2bab9045)
    V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 66dd4aad
    V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 66dd4aad
    V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 66dd4aad
    V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 66dd4aad
    V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 66dd4aad
    MD5 digest: OK (41aff697b960dfd3fd4a86b84690fdd8)

Comment: If you see the last comment I posted, the number of lines that are displayed is equal to the number of times I have performed the signing request.

Comment: The users complain that another procedure they follow after this signing is failing because of multiple signatures on the RPM packages.

Comment: rpm 4.4.2.3 is the version in CentOS 5 and it correctly does *not* add multiple signatures when I use it here. Are you sure that's the version in use here specifically? Is this CentOS 5 or some other distribution/etc.? According to the rpm CHANGES file `--addsign` became identical to `--resign` in rpm version 4.0.4.

Comment: Hm... I wonder if the type of signature matters. Can you test with an `RSA/SHA1` signature?

Comment: So I just did some testing and it turns out that I was incorrect in my assertion that this works correctly for me. It does not. I just reproduced this problem with that version of rpm on CentOS 5. Apparently my normal usages no longer hit the multiple signing case (without a `--delsign` in the middle). So JeffJohnson's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

See if rpm --delsign exists in rpm-4.4.2.3, and use that to delete all the signatures.

Comment: It does but I don't see why it should be necessary here. This seems to work correctly for me with that version on CentOS 5. (I know multiple signatures were supported in the past but I was under the impression that was already disabled in that version of rpm, which the man page seems to indicate as well.)

Comment: Um, I wrote the code and the man page and know what evil lurks. ;-) Multiple signatures can occur in different tags using different versions of rpm with different algorithms and header-only/header+payload signatures, but multiple signatures is hardly "supported" because one's mileage may vary.

Comment: Indeed. I had wondered at your "equivocation" on the presence of the option at that point given your relationship to the project. =) My point was mostly that while this would absolutely work I didn't see why it should be necessary here given what the behavior of `--addsign` is supposed to be (and seems to be in my usage of it). Though, as it turns out, I was incorrect and it *does* do this for me (apparently I just no longer hit that case). So my apologies.

Comment: Apologies unneeded ;-) rpm signatures have a hugely convolved history. IIRC RHEL4 packages were signed twice by accident because of --addsign/--resign different behavior(s) (now identical). That is/was why --delsign was added. The equivocation was solely because rpm-4.4.2.3 was 10y ago and in the midst of a rpm fork. with multiple implementations.

Comment: @JeffJohnson @EtanReisner , Thanks guys for your comments. It is not CentOs, it is SuseLinux 10.xx. Yeah `rpm --delsign` is definitely an option, but, in my opinion, an unnecessary one, as `--resign` shall do it. Anyways, I have advised the users to use `--delsign` for the time being :). Thanks a lot.